# Calling NASM 32bit SSE function in C

Tags: c, nasm

I'm trying to interface C and NASM to pass an array of float, make a few steps (subtract 2.0 to each element of the array) and then return the sum of the array result to C. The incorrect result printed is x = -34975412102996426752.000000

I don't understand why..
Thanks for help
This is the code of file (test.c and myfunc.nasm):

test.c:

```
extern float myfunc(float* a);


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float a[] = { 7.0, 24.0, 4.0, 6.1  };
    float x = myfunc(a);
    printf("x: %f\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

myfunc.nasm:

```
%include "sseutils.nasm"

section .data           
align 16
y:  dd  2.0 , 2.0, 2.0, 2.0


section .bss            

alignb 16
A:  resd    4

section .text           
global myfunc

a           equ         8   

myfunc:
push    ebp             
mov     ebp, esp        
push    ebx 

    movaps xmm0 , [ebp+a]
    movaps xmm1,[y]
    subps xmm0, xmm1

    haddpd  xmm0,xmm0
    haddpd  xmm0,xmm0

    movaps [A], xmm0
    fld dword[A]

pop     ebx
mov esp, ebp                
pop ebp                     
ret
```

Comment: Those `haddpd`'s are working on doubles, but you had floats in those registers.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: have I to change this istruction haddpd? I have tried this but nothing has changed